# How to change the colour of the legend column block in Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I've gone through the [legend docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend) and I can't find anything that will change the colour of the block that the legend displays corresponding to the series. My problem is that the bars are many  different colours, ranging from red to green, but the block on the legend is blue (I'm assuming the first colour in the list of colours).

However, when I click on a series to drill down, the legend is then changed to that series. Ideally I'd like to set it to be a blank box.

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: You can set the series level color and the point fillColor independently. For more specific help, you'll need to provide a working example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3dwSh/8/

Comment: Yet I want the legend color to be a blank box for the V_Genes series.

Comment: Since you are setting colors per point, color of series will be visible only in legend. You could set series color to light gray - http://jsfiddle.net/3dwSh/9/ or to 'none' - http://jsfiddle.net/3dwSh/10/

Comment: @KacperMadej Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this link --

http://jsfiddle.net/soravgarg/3dwSh/7/

```
here we have to change series->color value and this link i have get the red value you can check now...
```

Comment: Not quite. My data points for one of the series are coloured relative to other data, so I can't control the legend with the series colour value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting colors per point, color of series will be visible only in legend. You could set series color to light gray - http://jsfiddle.net/3dwSh/9/ or to `'none'` - http://jsfiddle.net/3dwSh/10